# How to build oozie 3.3.2 with Hive 0.11.0?

Tags: maven, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

How can i build oozie 3.3.2 for Hive 0.11.0 ? I have already modified necessary pom files to match hive version.I am getting following exception:

```
Failure to find org.apache.hive:hive-builtins:jar:0.11.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
```

**Update**: Can i use hive-builtins of Hive 0.10.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you edited hive-0.10.0 to hive-0.11.0 in OOZIE_HOME/pom.xml. hive-0.11.0 doesn't have hive-builtins.jar, so remove hive-bulitins dependency from OOZIE_HOME/sharelib/hive/pom.xml.
I showed you hive-builtins dependency lines in pom.xml, delete those lines from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```